# Getting blob gives 404 error

Tags: javascript, blob

could someone prompt me - how to save "blob in memory" to a file using Java Script?

e.g. I have in the page next blob-image:

```
<img src="blob:https%3A//drive.google.com/851b979c-92e9-4ef2-9152-8935f7793630" class="g-img">
```

and I need to save this blob to a file (png/jpg).
The next code just gives:

*GET blob:https%3A//drive.google.com/851b979c-92e9-4ef2-9152-8935f7793630 **404 (Not Found)***

so it seems, usual way to get the blobs doesn't work here.
Is there any workaround to save this blob-images from browser memory to a file, or, saying more exactly - to get them as a real blob using only "src" tag value?

Thank you.

```
var srcEl = evt.srcElement;
    var CurI = document.getElementsByClassName('g-img');
    [].forEach.call(CurI, function (el) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', el.src, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; // xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var myBlob = this.response;

      var reader = new window.FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(myBlob);
        console.log(myBlob);
  }
};
xhr.send();
        console.log(el.src);
     //   saveAs(myBlob, 'my2image.png');
     }
```

p.s. to use mediarecorder?